# I need to delete a product that is inside an object that in turn is inside a "cart" object that in turn is inside "carts"

Tags: javascript

I understand that to delete inside an object the ideal is filter + !== I have managed to apply it before. But this time it is a little more complicated, I have tried this logic and it is not working for me, maybe it is from the beginning poorly thought out. Sorry for not apply cameCase the i traslate my code for this.

```js
let carts = [{"id": 1, "products": [{"name": "aa", "id" : 1 },{"name": "bb", "id" : 2 }]},{"id": 2, "products": [{"name": "cc", "id" : 1 },{"name": "dd", "id" : 2 }]}]
deleteItem = (idcart, idProd) => {
    carts.map((cart) => {
        if (cart.id === idcart) {
            cart.products.map((product) => {
                if (product.id === idProd) {
                    let newproducts = cart.products.filter((product) => product.id !== idProd)
                    cart = newproducts;
                    let newcarts = carts.filter((cart) => cart.id !== idcart)
                    let carts = cart + newcarts
                    console.log(carts)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
deleteItem(2,1)
```

Comment: Take a look what [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does. Currently you are generating a new array and ignore the result. -- You should use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) or [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove an item from an array.

Comment: seeing ... `let carts = cart + newcarts` ... the real question seems to be, how does one `concat` arrays? Maybe even ... how does one `push` (an) item(s) into another array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to delete an item from your object. The idea here is to find the index, using another method called [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), where the deletion should be made and here's what we're going to do:

1. As the `deleteItem` accepts a `cartID` and a `productID` we will first of all fiind the index where the supplied `cartID` is found in the `carts` object (let's call that found index `cartIndex`).
2. Next, we'll try to find the index where `itemID` is found in `carts[cartIndex].products`.
3. Now, as we have all the indexes we need, we will simply `splice` the `products` (`carts[cartIndex].products`) and remove `1` item from there (which is the one having the supplied `itemID`).
4. At this stage, the wanted item should've been deleted from the `carts` object.

Here's a live demo illustrating what's being said:

```js
const carts = [{
    "id": 1,
    "products": [{
      "name": "aa",
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "name": "bb",
      "id": 2
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "products": [{
      "name": "cc",
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "name": "dd",
      "id": 2
    }]
  }],
  /** 
   * deletes an item from "carts" based on a "cartID" that has an item with id equals to "productID"
   */
  deleteItem = (cartID, productID) => {
    /** cartIdx: holds the index of the cart that has the "id"of "cartID" (or -1 if no item is found) */
    const cartIdx = carts.findIndex(c => c.id == cartID),
      /** itemIdx: holds the index of the product (inside the found cart) that has the "id" of "productID" (or -1 if no item is found) */
      itemIdx = cartIdx !== -1 ? carts[cartIdx].products.findIndex(i => i.id == productID) : null;
    /** if we have found the index of the item we're looking for (itemIdx > -1) then we delete that item using "splice" method */
    itemIdx > -1 && (x = carts[cartIdx].products.splice(itemIdx, 1));
  };

/** execute: the item where name = "aa" should be deleted */
deleteItem(1, 1);

/** print the carts after deletion */
console.log(carts);
```

Comment: hi! sry for the delay, thx for the response, it work good! but now i wanna understand something, why is a , after the findIndex(callback),

Comment: Hi @FedeWoodward , glad my attempt has helped you a bit. To answer your question, the `,` after `cartIdx = carts.findIndex(c => c.id == cartID)` is just a way to declare multiple `const`ants (variables) using the same `const` keyword. The `,` there is just to separate `cartIdx` and `itemIdx` declarations. I used this syntax to prevent redundant code like `const x = ...; const y = ...;` you get the idea I hope.